# Julia: How to obtain the types of every column of a DataFrame/Table?

Tags: dataframe, julia

There must be an easy way to obtain the column types of every column of a DataFrame. Currently, I do

```
using DataFrames
a = DataFrame(a = [1,2,3], str = ["a","b","c"], f = [0.0, 1.0, 5.0])
[eltype(Array(col)) for col in eachcol(a)]
```

Is the best way? Appreciate more efficient and elegant solutions

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to obtain the types and save the down so I can use them when deserializing it.

Answer (score 15):

You can broadcast `eltype` over the columns of the data frame:

```
df = DataFrame(
    x = [1, 2, 3],
    y = ["a", "b", "c"],
    z = [0.0, 1.0, 5.0]
)
```

```
julia> eltype.(eachcol(df))
3-element Array{DataType,1}:
 Int64
 String
 Float64
```

Note: Older versions of DataFrames.jl had an `eltypes` function, but it has been deprecated and removed from the package.

Comment: `eltypes` is deprecated on master. You can use `eltype.(eachcol(df))`.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Out of curiosity, is there an easy way to see in the github repo which functions are deprecated?

Comment: yes, https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/src/deprecated.jl if you want to check what is deprecated on master (otherwise choose a tag against which you want to perform the check). In general we will reduce the number of deprecations in the future. Now we are trying to stabilize API for 1.0 release, so e.g. it was decided that `eltypes` should be dropped as it is used very rarely and the alternative way to get the result using `eltype` is easy.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Oh nice, it's the very last line of that file. :) I looked at that file before, but I got a little lost in the details.